# ipv6-only hostname override ipv4-wildcard

Tags: domain-name-system

I have an ipv6-only host (accessible through a tunnel) and another host (webserver) with many subdomains on ipv4 and ipv6-wildcards

```
v6only.example.org AAAA 2001:DB8::1

*.example.org AAAA 2001:DB8::2
*.example.org A 203.0.113.2
```

How do I prevent v6only.example.org A to match the wildcard, resolving it to 203.0.113.2

Answer (score 0):

You don't. An explicit label (in this case `v6only.example.org`) will always be used in preference to a label generated from a wildcard. Just add an `A` record for the `v6only.example.org` name and it'll work as you want.

Comment: And what A do you suggest to give the ipv6-only?

Comment: One holding whatever IPv4 address you want returned for it, obviously.

Comment: What part of ipv6-only are you overlooking?

Comment: If you don't want an A record returned for that label, that is exactly the result you get from the config example in your question. Did you even try it before you wasted people's time by asking here?

Comment: @Lenne Calle is right, a wildcard is used **ONLY** if a direct match is not found, so in your case `v6only.example.org A` will return NODATA which means this specific record does not exist, but other records for the same name do exist. So your configuration works as intended, try it!

Comment: Just tested, it works as intended, but don't forget to flush your DNS resolver cache before testing :)